# Django 1.11. Servir arquivos tipo robots.txt, sitemap, etc

Tags: python-3.x, django

Preciso saber como servir esses arquivos que geralmente vão pra raiz do projeto. 
Estou fazendo uma rota para cada um deles no arquivo urls.py mas não me parece a forma correta.
Qual é o jeito certo?

Comment: 'Esses arquivos' você quer dizer arquivos estáticos ? -  Servir sobre qual contexto? Local ou produção ?

Comment: @OtávioReisPerkles acredito que sim, sejam estáticos. Seria em produção. Todo arquivo que mandam eu tenho que criar uma rota pra eles e jogá-los na pasta templates e não acho que isso seja certo. Na teoria seria só colocar na raiz e estaria de boa.

Comment: Está falando sobre ter uma pasta separada só pros arquivos estáticos? Já viu essa [página](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/howto/static-files/) na documentação?

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente o mais correto é delegar essa tarefa para o Nginx ou Apache, que na maioria dos casos já vão estar servindo os arquivos estáticos do projeto.

Caso esteja utilizando Nginx, segue um exemplo:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  access_log /opt/example.com/logs/nginx_access.log combined;
  error_log /opt/example.com/logs/nginx_error.log;

  location /static/ {
    alias /opt/example.com/static/;
  }

  location /media/ {
    alias /opt/example.com/media/;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    rewrite (.*) /static/img/favicon.ico;
  }

  # restante do arquivo de configuração...

}
```

Eu costumo usar essa configuração para `favicon.ico`, `robots.txt` e algumas vezes para o `sitemap.xml` quando este é estático. Se sua aplicação for uma voltada para conteúdo SEO é importante, talvez valeria a pena considerar o [sitemaps framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sitemaps/), que faz parte das apps Django.

Mas, voltando à sua pergunta. O exemplo acima seria para o Nginx. Caso esteja usando Apache, segue um exemplo retirado da [documentação oficial](http://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi.html#serving-files):

```
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```